# Uploading new android app with apk of unpublished app

Tags: android, google-play

I lost my keystore, and hence couldn't update my app with the new keystore. I unpublished my old app (it's internal - not many users), and tried uploading the apk as a new app. Play store tells me that I need to use a different package name since it's being used by one of my other applications. Why is it considering the package name for an unpublished app and how do I prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is it considering the package name for an unpublished app?

Google Play looks at all apps ever uploaded to Google Play (whether published or just as a draft) when looking for a unique package name.

> How do I prevent it from doing so?

You cannot. You'll have to change the package name for your new app. Save and backup your keystore!

Comment: Yeah, after 15 minutes of googling and not finding anything, I figured refactoring the package name would be the easier option. Thanks for the response anyway